# Simple Yahtzee simulation not giving proper result?

Tags: python, python-2.7, simulation, montecarlo

I am working through the MIT OpenCourseWare intro to computer programming course and I am not sure if I am solving a simple simulation the right way.

> 2. What is the probability of rolling a Yahtzee! on the first roll? That is, what is the
>      probability of rolling five 6-sided dice, and having them all display the same number?
> 3. Write a Monte Carlo simulation to solve the above problem (the Yahtzee problem), and
>      submit your code as

So the probability of rolling a Yahtzee is 1/1296 or about .077%

Here is my code to run the simulation:

```
import random

def runYahtzee(numTrials):
    """Runs the classes version of the yahtzee simulation"""

    success = 0
    for i in range(numTrials):

        dices = []
        for i in range(6):
            dices.append(random.randrange(1,7))
        #print dices

        state = True
        for dice in dices:
            if dice != dices[0]:
                state = False
        if state == True:
            print "You got a Yahtzee"
            print dices
            success += 1

    print "numTrials is: " + str(numTrials)
    print "Success is: " + str(success)
    rate = float(success)/numTrials
    return rate

runYahtzee(10000000)
```

Running the program multiple times, I get around .0001258 each time.  This is .012%, but the actual probability is around .077%. Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: As a curiosity, I did some research to see if your method for determining whether a set of dice is a yahtzee could be improved, and it is surprisingly good! I expected `len(set(dice)) == 1` to be better, but this outperforms it by a factor of 2. I also expected `functools.reduce(operator.eq, dice)` to be better, but this edges it out, too.

Comment: @AdamSmith What about `d0 = randrange(1,7); all(d0 == randrange(1,7) for _ in range(4))`?  (just skip the creation of dices altogether).  The OP's original is not optimized: you could break out of the loop as soon as you determine that `state` is False.

Comment: `len(set(dice)) == 1` works out to be the quickest for me (Py3) but then `random.choices(range(1, 7), k=5)` is also faster than `5 * random.randrange(1, 7)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is rolling 6 dice instead of 5.

0.001258 * 6 = 0.0007548

... which is close to your 0.077%

Change your loop:

```
    for i in range(5):
```

---

BTW, the plural is `dice`; the singular is `die`.  `dices` is *wrong*, unless you're trying to be amusing.  In that case, you can use the singular "douse" ... *never* say die!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write it (Python 3):

```
from collections import Counter
from random import randint

def roll():
    return randint(1, 6)

def is_yahtzee(num_dice = 5):
    first = roll()
    return all(roll() == first for _ in range(1, num_dice))

def montecarlo(fn, num_trials):
    return Counter(fn() for _ in range(num_trials))

def main():
    num_trials = 10000000
    result = montecarlo(is_yahtzee, num_trials)
    prob = result[True] / num_trials
    print(
        "After {} trials, probability of Yahtzee is {:0.5f}%"
        .format(num_trials, 100. * prob)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
After 10000000 trials, probability of Yahtzee is 0.07605%
```

Note that keeping your functions short generally makes them easier to understand and test.